# Pythagorean identities: how do I calculate the proper cos sign?

Tags: c++, math, trigonometry

Having the formula

> cos(x) = sqrt(1-sin(x)^2)

I am trying to test it in my simple program, but I don't get where is my fault.
The results are incorrect in the end.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    std::vector<float> data;

    constexpr float angleAdd = 360.0/10.0;
    constexpr float M_PI_DIVIDED_BY_180 = M_PI/180.0;

    for (auto angle = 0.0; angle < 360.0; angle += angleAdd) {
        data.push_back(angle);
    }

    //
    float res1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
        res1 += sin(data[i]*M_PI_DIVIDED_BY_180);
        res1 += cos(data[i]*M_PI_DIVIDED_BY_180);
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n";

    float res2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
        float angle = data[i];      
        float sinVal = sin(angle*M_PI_DIVIDED_BY_180);

        bool isPositiveSign = (angle >= 0 && angle <= 90) || (angle >= 270 && angle <= 360);
        float cosVal = sqrt(1 -sinVal*sinVal);
        if (isPositiveSign) {
            cosVal = fabs(cosVal);
        } else {
            cosVal = -1.0*fabs(cosVal);
        }

        res2 += sinVal;
        res2 += cosVal;
    }

    std::cout << "res1: " << res1 << " res2: " << res2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It gives me:

> res1: -6.89606e-07 res2: -3.57628e-07

Obviously, `res2` is wrong.
I am sure something is messed up in my calculations of the cos sign, but I cannot figure out - what.
Could the community give me some hints what is wrong here?

Comment: "Obviously, res2 is wrong". Why? What value did you expect?

Comment: This is not a valid test, as round-off error also contributes. The sum should really be zero, so all you see are two different round-off errors. Both are of the expected magnitude, i.e. close to `std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()`.

Comment: `res1` and `res2` should be *nearly* equal, aren't they?

Comment: what about my calculations of `isPositiveSign`. is that valid?

Comment: There is no point in applying `fabs` to `cosVal`, as the result of `sqrt` is never negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number you're computing as `res1` or `res2` would be zero, if you could do the computation without error. However, floating-point arithmetic always incurs errors. So, the two different results you're obtaining are simply two different representations of floating-point zero to the accuracy of your calculations – do them with double precision and you find results with smaller magnitude.

Also note that `std::cos()` and `std::sin()` do not *exactly* satisfy the identity `square(sin)+square(cos)=1`. Therefore,

```
assert(square(std::cos(x)) != 1 - square(std::sin(x)));
```

for most values of `x` (exceptions are presumably only 0 and perhaps pi).

Since `res1` and `res2` are both approximations of zero, their signs are arbitrary (though deterministic). You will get different results (but still consistent with being approximations of zero) if you change `angleAdd` to another divisor of `360`.

All this implies, of course, that your program tests nothing and any values for `res1` and `res2` that are within a few `std::numeric_limits<X>::epsilon()` from zero (where `X` is the floating-point type used) are valid. There is no *correct* answer.

Comment: thanks. one moment i don't understand is that `res1` and `res2` might have different signs if, for example, I have `angleAdd = 360.0/2.0`;

Comment: in this case I get `res1: 3.33067e-16 res2: -8.74228e-08`. is this still correct?

Comment: pi isn't exactly representable in a `float` so there's no reason to expect that `sin(pi)==0`. In fact, the rounding error in pi is about `epsilon` and the derivative of sin(x) at x=pi is 1, so the expected resulting error in sin(x) is already epsilon merely because of round-off errors in the input.

Comment: @fres There is some good reading at ["What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic or Why don’t my numbers add up?"](http://floating-point-gui.de/).